# Android ADT plugin isn't installing on my machine

Tags: android

I've installed the following:

- JDK
- Android SDK
- Eclipse Classic 3.7

Now I'm trying to install the ADT plugin for eclipse, but in the install process I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)
```

How do I go about resolving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started from the beginning, removed Eclipse, Android SDK etc, then downloaded everything again and re-installed. Seems to be working know, weird?!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now, and I solved it running eclipse as admin...

- Windows 7 pro x64
- Eclipse Indigo

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Issue, but I updated Eclipse and the Android SDK, it worked ! i guess no need to re install all the stuff.
I was running Eclipse Helios 64bit